# Context.Wait(Function) doesn't register and runs the previous context.Wait on message received

Tags: c#, botframework

EDIT: This has been solved. If anyone runs into a similar issue my problem was that I had forgotten to annotate models used as instance variales in the dialog as [Serializable].

When I'm using `context.Wait(MyFunction)` it doesn't get called as I respond to the bot. I'm not entirely sure whether this is because the dialog gets dropped (done) so when the new message comes in it just runs the dialog again or whether it's cause the `context.Wait` call is somehow not registered and thus the previously sent in `context.Wait(func)` is used. Botframework version is the latest of the 3.x and what I'm trying to to is a custom `QnAMakerDialog`.

The dialog flow looks like

> MessageReceived -> Task HandleMessage -> Task HandleMessageWhenMoreThanOneAnswer

(This is where I use the Context.Wait(function).

Any tips on how I could go about debugging this?

I can post the code if necessary! Any help appreciated!

Code: The base of the code is: https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/blob/master/QnAMakerDialog/QnAMakerDialog/QnADialog.cs

And here's the functions called in order. The dialog is called from the RootDialog with a context.Forward().

```
    [Serializable]
public class TestDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    private string _baseUri;
    private string _endpointKey;
    private string _subscriptionKey;
    private string _knowledgeBaseId;
    private int _maxAnswers;
    private List<QnADialog.Models.Metadata> _metadataBoost;
    private List<QnADialog.Models.Metadata> _metadataFilter;
    private QnADialog.Models.QuestionResponse.QnAMakerResult qnaMakerResults;
    //private QnADialog.Models.UserFeedback userFeedback; <--- THIS destroys the flow

    public string BaseUri { get => _baseUri; set => _baseUri = value; }
    public string EndpointKey { get => _endpointKey; set => _endpointKey = value; }
    public string SubscriptionKey { get => _subscriptionKey; set => _subscriptionKey = value; }
    public string KnowledgeBaseId { get => _knowledgeBaseId; set => _knowledgeBaseId = value; }
    public int MaxAnswers { get => _maxAnswers; set => _maxAnswers = value; }



    public List<QnADialog.Models.Metadata> MetadataBoost { get => _metadataBoost; set => _metadataBoost = value; }
    public List<QnADialog.Models.Metadata> MetadataFilter { get => _metadataFilter; set => _metadataFilter = value; }

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {

        this.BaseUri = "";
        this.EndpointKey = "";
        this.KnowledgeBaseId = "";
        this.SubscriptionKey = "";
        this.MaxAnswers = 5;
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
    {
        var message = await item;

        //this.userFeedback = new QnADialog.Models.UserFeedback { userId = message.From.Id, userQuestion = message.Text };
        await context.PostAsync("MessageReceived");

        await this.HandleMessage(context, message.Text);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as IMessageActivity;

        await context.PostAsync(activity.Text);

        await this.HandleMessage(context, activity.Text);
    }

    private async Task HandleMessage(IDialogContext context, string queryText)
    {
        var response = await GetQnAMakerResponse(queryText, BaseUri, KnowledgeBaseId, EndpointKey);

        //if (HandlerByMaximumScore == null)
        //{
        //    HandlerByMaximumScore =
        //        new Dictionary<QnAMakerResponseHandlerAttribute, QnAMakerResponseHandler>(GetHandlersByMaximumScore());
        //}

        if (response.Answers.Any() && response.Answers.First().QnaId == 0)
        {
            await NoMatchHandler(context, queryText);
        }
        else
        {
            if (response.Answers.Count() == 1)
            {
                await DefaultMatchHandler(context, queryText, response);
            }
            else
            {
                //this.qnaMakerResults = response;
                //var qnaList = qnaMakerResults.Answers;
                //await context.PostAsync(createHeroCard(context, qnaList));
                //context.Wait(HandleQuestionResponse);
                await QnAFeedbackHandler(context, queryText, response);
            }

        }
    }

    private async Task<QnADialog.Models.QuestionResponse.QnAMakerResult> GetQnAMakerResponse(string query, string baseUri, string knowledgeBaseId, string endpointKey)
    {
        string responseString;
        var qnamakerBaseUri = baseUri;
        var knowledgebaseId = knowledgeBaseId; // Use knowledge base id created.
        var qnamakerEndpointKey = endpointKey; //Use endpoint key assigned to you.

        //Build the URI
        var qnamakerUriBase = new Uri(qnamakerBaseUri);
        var builder = new UriBuilder($"{qnamakerUriBase}/knowledgebases/{knowledgebaseId}/generateAnswer");

        //Add the question as part of the body
        var request = new QnADialog.Models.QuestionRequest()
        {
            Question = query,
            Top = MaxAnswers,
            UserId = "QnAMakerDialog"
        };



        var postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

        //Send the POST request
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            //Set the encoding to UTF8
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            //Add the subscription key header
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"EndpointKey {qnamakerEndpointKey}");
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            responseString = client.UploadString(builder.Uri, postBody);
        }

        //De-serialize the response
        try
        {
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnADialog.Models.QuestionResponse.QnAMakerResult>(responseString);
            return response;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to deserialize QnA Maker response string.");
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task DefaultMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText, QnADialog.Models.QuestionResponse.QnAMakerResult result)
    {
        var messageActivity = ProcessResultAndCreateMessageActivity(context, ref result);
        messageActivity.Text = result.Answers.First().Answer;
        await context.PostAsync(messageActivity);
        await AnswerFeedback(context);
    }

    public virtual async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("No match was found");
        //throw new Exception("Sorry, I cannot find an answer to your question.");
    }

    private async Task AnswerFeedback(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.PostAsync("HandleMessage");
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        CardAction cardActionYes = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = "imBack",
            Title = "Yes",
            Value = "Yes"
        };
        CardAction cardActionNo = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = "imBack",
            Title = "No",
            Value = "No"
        };
        HeroCard card = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "Was the answer helpful?",
            Buttons = cardButtons
        };
        cardButtons.Add(cardActionYes);
        cardButtons.Add(cardActionNo);
        Attachment atch = card.ToAttachment();
        reply.Attachments.Add(atch);
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
        context.Wait(this.HandleHelpfulResponse);
    }

    private async Task HandleHelpfulResponse(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as IMessageActivity;
        if (activity.Text == "Yes")
        {
 //              await context.PostAsync($"{this.userFeedback.kbQuestionId} 
 - {this.userFeedback.userId} - {this.userFeedback.userQuestion}");
        }
        else if (activity.Text == "No")
        {
           await context.PostAsync("NOPNORP");
        }
        context.Done(new Object());
    }

    protected static IMessageActivity ProcessResultAndCreateMessageActivity(IDialogContext context, ref QnADialog.Models.QuestionResponse.QnAMakerResult result)
    {
        var message = context.MakeMessage();

        var attachmentsItemRegex = new Regex("((&lt;attachment){1}((?:\\s+)|(?:(contentType=&quot;[\\w\\/-]+&quot;))(?:\\s+)|(?:(contentUrl=&quot;[\\w:/.=?-]+&quot;))(?:\\s+)|(?:(name=&quot;[\\w\\s&?\\-.@%$!£\\(\\)]+&quot;))(?:\\s+)|(?:(thumbnailUrl=&quot;[\\w:/.=?-]+&quot;))(?:\\s+))+(/&gt;))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matches = attachmentsItemRegex.Matches(result.Answers.First().Answer);

        foreach (var attachmentMatch in matches)
        {
            result.Answers.First().Answer = result.Answers.First().Answer.Replace(attachmentMatch.ToString(), string.Empty);

            var match = attachmentsItemRegex.Match(attachmentMatch.ToString());
            string contentType = string.Empty;
            string name = string.Empty;
            string contentUrl = string.Empty;
            string thumbnailUrl = string.Empty;

            foreach (var group in match.Groups)
            {
                if (group.ToString().ToLower().Contains("contenttype="))
                {
                    contentType = group.ToString().ToLower().Replace(@"contenttype=&quot;", string.Empty).Replace("&quot;", string.Empty);
                }
                if (group.ToString().ToLower().Contains("contenturl="))
                {
                    contentUrl = group.ToString().ToLower().Replace(@"contenturl=&quot;", string.Empty).Replace("&quot;", string.Empty);
                }
                if (group.ToString().ToLower().Contains("name="))
                {
                    name = group.ToString().ToLower().Replace(@"name=&quot;", string.Empty).Replace("&quot;", string.Empty);
                }
                if (group.ToString().ToLower().Contains("thumbnailurl="))
                {
                    thumbnailUrl = group.ToString().ToLower().Replace(@"thumbnailurl=&quot;", string.Empty).Replace("&quot;", string.Empty);
                }
            }

            var attachment = new Attachment(contentType, contentUrl, name: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? name : null, thumbnailUrl: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbnailUrl) ? thumbnailUrl : null);
            message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }

        return message;
    }

    private async Task QnAFeedbackHandler(IDialogContext context, string userQuery, QnADialog.Models.QuestionResponse.QnAMakerResult results)
    {

        //this.feedbackRecord = new UserFeedback() { userQuestion = userQuery };
        this.qnaMakerResults = results;
        var qnaList = results.Answers;
        //var contextTest2 = context;
        await context.PostAsync(createHeroCard(context, qnaList));

        context.Wait(HandleQuestionResponse); // funkar inte....

    }

    protected IMessageActivity createHeroCard(IDialogContext context, QnADialog.Models.QuestionResponse.QnaAnswer[] options)
    {
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        foreach (var ans in options)
        {
            CardAction cardAction = new CardAction()
            {
                Type = "imBack",
                Title = ans.Questions[0],
                Value = ans.Questions[0]
            };
            cardButtons.Add(cardAction);
        }

        CardAction none = new CardAction()
        {
            Type = "imBack",
            Title = Resource.noneOfTheAboveOption,
            Value = Resource.noneOfTheAboveOption
        };
        cardButtons.Add(none);

        HeroCard card = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "Did you mean?",
            Buttons = cardButtons
        };
        Attachment atch = card.ToAttachment();
        reply.Attachments.Add(atch);
        return reply;
    }

    protected async Task HandleQuestionResponse(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var selection = await result as IMessageActivity;
        context.PostAsync("LastStep");
        if (this.qnaMakerResults != null)
        {
            bool match = false;
            foreach (var qnaMakerResult in this.qnaMakerResults.Answers)
            {
                if (qnaMakerResult.Questions[0].Equals(selection.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    await context.PostAsync(qnaMakerResult.Answer);
                    match = true;

                    //if (userFeedback != null)
                    //{
                    //    userFeedback.kbQuestionId = qnaMakerResult.QnaId;
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
        await this.AnswerFeedback(context);
    }
}
```

RootDialog:

```
namespace customQnADialog.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            await context.Forward(new CustomQnADialog(), ResumeAfterQnADialog, activity, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        private async Task ResumeAfterQnADialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
```

Comment: "Any tips on how I could go about debugging this?" yes: post your code please

Comment: Yes, please post the code (it is necessary).

Comment: Alright, I added the code... There's some more code in the dialog but it's not called in the case that causes the error, lmk if you'd like to see that aswell.

Comment: "There's some more code in the dialog but it's not called in the case that causes the error, lmk if you'd like to see that aswell"... yes, add all the Dialog and the calling one as you have global problem on your navigation implementation. We will not try to guess and make assumptions on every possibility

Comment: Please share the entire class.

Comment: Alright, sorry. It's quite long, maybe there's a better way to post longer codesnippets. I've edited again. The root dialog and controllers are very basic.

Comment: So I've remade the dialog step by step to see what makes disrupts it and it's when I added the instance variable for the userFeedback that it abrupts the dialogflow. I have no clue as to how or why though? Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind it still does the same thing, adding or removing that instance variable does however make it not go in to the messagereceived at all but goes out of the dialog after the startAsync function.

Comment: Im almost positive it has something to do with the instance variables though. What disrupts the dialog flow seems to be when I set the qnaMakerResults instance variable in the dialog object, which is executed within the dialog flow in the qnaFeedBackHandler function.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out the issue with the instance variables. It's cause I hadn't added the [Serializeable] annotation to the class. I should have posted my models aswell, my bad, sorry if that wasted anyones time.

Comment: Hi @Alun, glad to hear you solve the problem. In your code, I find that you forward to `CustomQnADialog` from your root dialog, I'd like to know when and where `TestDialog` is called.